# OpenGL ES3 framebuffer draw depth in red scale

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, framebuffer, opengl-es-3.0, shadow-mapping

So after hard work to make directional light shadow map work finally I can see a shadow map rendered on a quad but it is drawn only with depth `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` and type `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` , or `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F` and type `GL_FLOAT` but it is in red scale not gray scale

[image: Depth map]

the problem is I used many methods to calculate the depth to draw the shadow but no shadow appears.

```
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
            glGenFramebuffers(1, &depthMapFBO);
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
            glGenTextures(1, &depthMap);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);

            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap, 0);
            glDrawBuffers(1, GL_NONE);
            glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
            glCullFace(GL_BACK);
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    LOGI("framebuffer incomplete");
}
```

and the fragment is:

```
uniform mediump sampler2DShadow  shadowMap;
......
float bias = 0.005;
float visibility = 1.0;
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
    int index = i;
    visibility -= 0.2*(1.0-texture( shadowMap, vec3(FragPosLightSpace.xy + poissonDisk[index]/700.0,  (FragPosLightSpace.z-bias)/FragPosLightSpace.w) ));           
}
result =light.intensity* (visibility * (diffuse + specular));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...but it is in red scale not gray scale

A texture with an depth component format, such as `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` or `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F` has only 1 color channel, the **red** color channel.
If you read data from a texture sampler, where a depth component texture is bound to, then the green, blue and alpha channel are set automatically.

The [Image Format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format) specification of Khronos group says:

> Image formats do not have to store each component. When the shader samples such a texture, it will still resolve to a 4-value RGBA vector. The components not stored by the image format are filled in automatically. Zeros are used if R, G, or B is missing, while a missing Alpha always resolves to 1.
> **Note:** Texture swizzling can change what the missing values are.

Because of that, the red color is set, the green and blue color is set to 0 and the alpha channel is 1. The causes the opaque red surface.

If you want to read a grayscale color from a depth component texture, then you have to read the **red** color channel and you have to apply the red color channel to the green and blue color, too.

You have to adapt the code like this:

```
float depth          = texture( shadowMap, ..... ).r;
vec3  depthGrayscale = vec3( depth );
```

or this:

```
vec3  depthGrayscale = texture( shadowMap, ..... ).rrr;
```